# Touchscreen tap counts as double left click on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, touchscreen

After upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, the touchscreen is unusable. Tapping once on screen acts as double click of mouse button. Eg. in GNOME when I want to click on "Show Apps" it shows them and closes within a second as the second

Seen on Lenovo Yoga 3 PRO.

Comment: Very interesting and strange behavior. I'm not sure if I got it totally fixed, but this helped:  Settings >> Universal Access >> Pointing & Clicking -> SET ->Mouse Keys (OFF) Click Assist (OFF) and double-click delay to (Minumum - scroll bar to most left)

Answer (score 1):

Same here with a Dell 2314ht Touchscreen. It is correctly detected as an 'Advanced Silicon S.A.' device.
[`libinput debug-events`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Troubleshooting) detects the following sequence for a single tap: `TOUCH_DOWN`, `TOUCH_FRAME`, `TOUCH_UP`, `TOUCH_FRAME`. Seems ok, however not sure what the `TOUCH_FRAME` is about?

Like in your case, tapping on the left Ubuntu 18.04 starterbar, (e.g. the Apps button) generates two clicks:

- First click on event `TOUCH_DOWN`
- Second click on event `TOUCH_UP`

That is, if one touch-and-hold the Apps button, only one click is generated. When removing the finger another click is fired.

Anyway, far more interesting is that the behavior depend INTO WHAT FIELD one taps:

- Using the onscreen keyboard to type a command into console, everything works fine
- Using the onscreen keyboard to type a web-address into Firefox, every key needs to be pressed TWICE (loses every second tap)

`libinput debug-events` reports exactly the same sequence for all the above. Therefore, my best guess is that this issue is located 'above/after' libinput towards X.org.

Comment: Very interesting and strange behavior. I'm not sure if I got it totally fixed, but this helped:  Settings >> Universal Access >> Pointing & Clicking -> SET ->Mouse Keys (OFF) Click Assist (OFF) and double-click delay to (Minumum - scroll bar to most left)

Comment: Thanks for the response but actually did not solve my issue, Mouse Keys and Click Assist were already OFF.
Adjusting the slider to min or max does not change the behaviour

Comment: True, same here. Sometimes it requires double tapping, sometimes only once. Couldn't figure out what triggers that to happens.

Comment: Just again played with 'libinput debug-events' to log the events generated by the touchscreen. I would have expected an event 'TOUCH_DOWN' on lowering the finger on the touchscreen and another event 'TOUCH_UP' on raising it.

However, lowering creates TWO events: 'TOUCH_DOWN' 'TOUCH_FRAME'

Raising also creates TWO events: 'TOUCH_UP' 'TOUCH_FRAME'

What is the 'TOUCH_FRAME' event for?
And, could it be that depending on the application (starterbar, console, firefox) consuming it leading to the described different behavior?

Michael

Comment: Same weird issue here with a dell 7373, the issue is only with the xorg session, using wayland the issues go away (but I am not able to launch a "right click" action)